# Finding the Minimum of Array while passing by reference

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors, min, function-definition

I am trying to write a **void Function** using **pass by reference** , that finds the minimum of an Array while only giving a pointer of an Array and the length of the Array as a Parameter into the Function.

I keep getting errors like:

> Incomplete type is not allowed (in the main function)
> assignment to 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

This is my code:

```c
void minimum(int *iArray[], int count)
{

    int min = iArray[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (min > iArray[i])

        *iArray = min;

    }

}


int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {4, 6, 9, 5};

    printf("%d", minimum(numbers, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

Can you help me out how i can do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration and the definition of the function are incorrect.

In this function call

```
minimum(numbers, 4)
```

the array is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int *`. But the corresponding function parameter has the type `int *[]` that is adjusted by the compiler to the type `int **`..

Thus for example in this line

```
int min = iArray[0];
```

the object `min` of the type `int` is initialized by a pointer of the type `int *`.

Also it is a bad idea to change the source array in a function that finds the minimal element.

And as the function has the return type `void` then the call of the function `printf` is invalid

```
printf("%d", minimum(numbers, 4));
```

The function should be declared and defined the following way

```
int * minimum( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    const int *min = a;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < *min ) min = a + i;
    }

    return ( int * )min;
}
```

And the call of the function will look like

```
int *min = minimum(numbers, 4);

printf( "The minimum value is %d at position %tu.\n", *min, min - numbers );
```

Alternatively the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t minimum( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    size_t min = a;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < a[min] ) min = i;
    }

    return min;
}
```

And the call of the function will look like

```
size_t min = minimum(numbers, 4);

printf( "The minimum value is %d at position %zu.\n", numbers[min], min );
```

Answer (score 0):

`numbers` is pointer to first element of the array. Thus your function definition should be like :-

```
int minimum(int *iArray, int count)
```

or

```
int minimum(int iArray[], int count)
```

Note: Your logic for finding minimum has some errors and you are supposed to return the `min` for it to be printed with `printf`. Your complete code will look like :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minimum(int *iArray, int count)
{

    int min = iArray[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (min > iArray[i])
            min = iArray[i];

    }
    return min;
}


int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {4, 6, 9, 5};

    printf("%d", minimum(numbers, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the function return in case when it is called with a negative value of count or count equal to 0?

Comment: As we had initialized "min" as first element of array that is element at 0th-index of array thus when you pass count equals to 0 or negative, for loop won't run and "min" will be returned and "min" was initialized as first element that is element at 0th-index, therefore first element of array would be returned.

Comment: AGHAD When  count is equal to 0 or to a negative value that means that the range is empty and  this statement  int min = iArray[0]; invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: It depends on whether range is empty or not, you can pass count equals to 0 even when array is not empty, but otherwise you would get garbage value.